# regarding WPF validation;

Tags: wpf, validation

In my application I have a model and viewmodel which implement IDataError this all works but for example when I open view for adding new customer if my validation rule requires First and Last name not to be null or empty those validations are immediately evaluated and user sees form with errors asking them to enter those data. how can I just show clean entry form but still show validation when property changes or input lost focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first if your rule say that first and lastname should not be empty - its right that the user see the validation error.

what i have done is to use a ValidationTemplate for empty values, so that the user just see a "*" for requiered field.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplateEmpty" >
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="*" Margin="0,0,3,0" Foreground="Red" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyAdornedElement,Path=AdornedElement.Visibility}"
                   ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=MyAdornedElement,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdornedElement" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushErrorLight}" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationTemplateEmpty}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I know technically and l0ogically this validation error is correct as when I sad that hey rule FirstName must never be empty or null when binding starts it checks for this property and as validation can not be satisfied it raises error. This is normal and I understand this, but what I want to do is disable (this is already done and depends on models validation result) and not to show error when form first loads and only display them if for example FirstnameInput lost focus without entering any data

Comment: the users of my app like the mark of empty textboxes when they are required - the good thing is you do not have to change your validationlogic in your viewmodel. for unit test its even easier because you do not have to handle a loadevent or isloaded variable

Answer (score 1):

If you implements `IDataErrorInfo` why do you use validation rule?

Comment: U misunderstood me. When I sad validation rule I i wanted to say business rule to be satisfied. so the point here is that, If it says "mark property as invalid if it is null or empty" when new form is loaded all rules are initially failed so I do not want this functionality but want to be able to still have on property change mode to validate inputs

Comment: @Rati_Ge: It's simple. Add boolean field to your view model class, for instance, name it `_isChangeOnce = false`. To your validation logic add condition that `_isChangedOnce` should be `true`. And change this field to `true` when any property changes.

Comment: hey this sounds reasonable and this is what I was thinking of, but as view model is concerned it is really ok for me, but as Model is concerned it is self tracking entities and raises propertychange and what u suggest means I have to change this property to every setter as I do not know which one will fire fist. I am now thinking of just automating this process and even for validation i think this will be some sort of solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario the validation you implemented is wrong. While in other situations a LastName property cannot be empty in this scenario it is allowed.

What is not allowed, is saving a Customer with empty fields.

So you have to adjust your validation in this ViewModel accordingly.

To have input validation the way you describe it (lost focus) is impossible if you want to give the user the freedom to enter the fields in random order.

I see two acceptable ways:

1. Keep the input/field validation but make it less *in your face*; just a simple mark next to the textbox.
2. Validate the Cutomer object when clicking the Save button and setting errors in the UI. You could even code the CanExecute of the SaveCommand but that might make the validation (when can I save, what did I do wrong) more obscure.

Comment: Some points of your suggestion seems very interesting but the idea of validation is user is notified before clicking save button and save button needs to be disabled till data is valid as this is wizard and it is mandatory to sizable next button if data on presented page of the wizard is not valid. another interesting point here is that I have custom action which simulates enter key as tab so I have something like enter key traversal. so first input is focused and user generally navigates using enter key.

Comment: That is not the windows way of working. Tab = next field, Enter = save.